How to call a child component's function in Vue 3 by clicking a button in the parent?
I have a component named 'MediaImport' which has a 'upload' function in its 'methods', and I need it to be executed when clicking the appropriate button in the parent component where the 'MediaUpload' component is located, and after its execution, navigate to another route. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here and how it should look correctly?
Page VideoRecognition code:
<script lang="ts">
import Button from 'primevue/button';

import MediaImport from '@/components/MediaImport';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import WebSocketService from '@/utils/WebSocketService';
//import { ws } from '@/main';

export default {
  name: "VideoRecognition",
  emits: ['upload-media'],
  setup(_, { emit }) {
    const hasFiles = ref<Boolean>(false);
    const hasUploaded = ref<Boolean>(false);
    const mediaObjectUrl = ref<String>("");

    const handleHasFiles = (value: boolean) => {
      hasFiles.value = value;
    };

    const handleHasUploaded = (value: boolean) => {
        hasUploaded.value = value;
    };

    const handleSendMediaObjectUrl = (path: string) => {
        mediaObjectUrl.value = path;
    };

    const ws = new WebSocketService();
    const router = useRouter();
    const goToRecognitionView = () => {
        emit('upload-media', true);
        if (hasFiles.value && hasUploaded.value) {
            console.log(hasUploaded.value)
            //ws.send("video_recognition_media_object_url", mediaObjectUrl.value);
            //ws.close();
            //router.push('/recognition');
        } else {
            console.log('Focus')
        }
    };

    return { hasFiles, handleHasFiles, handleHasUploaded, handleSendMediaObjectUrl, goToRecognitionView };
  },
  components: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-reserved-component-names
    Button,
    MediaImport,
  },
};
</script>

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div class="flex flex-col justify-center w-full">
                <div class="w-full flex-auto flex flex-col justify-center items-center border-2 border-solid border-surface-200 dark:border-surface-700 rounded-md bg-[#1e2d4b] font-medium p-4">
                    <p class="pb-4">Select video to recognize</p>
                    <MediaImport ref="MediaImport" name="media[]" url="/api/upload" mediaType="video" accept="video/*" @has-files="handleHasFiles" @media-object-url="handleSendMediaObjectUrl" @has-uploaded="handleHasUploaded" :maxFileSize="512000000" :auto="true" chooseLabel="Browse" />
                </div>
                <div class="flex pt-4 justify-end">
                    <Button label="Next" icon="pi pi-arrow-right" iconPos="right" @click="goToRecognitionView" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

Component MediaImport code:
<script lang="ts">
import Message from 'primevue/message';
import BaseMediaImport from './BaseMediaImport.vue';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { Comment, ref } from 'vue';
import { randomNumber } from '@/utils/randomNumber';

export interface MediaFile extends File {
    name: string;
    type: string;
    size: number;
    objectURL?: string;
    path?: string;
}

export default {
    name: 'MediaImport',
    extends: BaseMediaImport,
    emits: ['select', 'before-upload', 'progress', 'error', 'clear', 'remove', 'has-files', 'media-object-url', 'upload', 'uploader', 'has-uploaded', 'before-send'],
    setup() {
        const mediaUpload = ref<Boolean>(false);
        const handleMediaUpload = (state: boolean) => {
            mediaUpload.value = state;
        }

        return { handleMediaUpload };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            files: [] as MediaFile[],
            uploadedFiles: [] as MediaFile[],
            messages: [] as String[],
            focused: false,
            progress: null,
            acceptedTypes: '',
            showDragOverIcon: false,
            uploadedFileCount: 0
        };
    },
    methods: {
        upload() {
            if (this.customUpload) {
                if (this.fileLimit) {
                    this.uploadedFileCount += this.files.length;
                }

                this.$emit('uploader', { files: this.files });
                this.clear();
            } else {
                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                let formData = new FormData();

                this.$emit('before-upload', {
                    xhr: xhr,
                    formData: formData
                });

                for (let file of this.files) {
                    const minFileSizeToCreatePart = 80 * 1024 * 1024 // 80 MB
                    const fileName = this.generateUniqueFileName(file.name);
                    if (file.size >= minFileSizeToCreatePart) {
                        let start = 0;
                        let partSize = 60 * 1024 * 1024; // 60 MB
                        while (start < file.size) {
                            let chunk = file.slice(start, start + partSize);
                            formData.append(`${this.name}[]`, chunk, `${fileName}.part${Math.ceil((start + 1) / partSize)}`);
                            start += partSize;
                        }
                    } else {
                        formData.append(this.name, file, fileName);
                    }
                }

                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (event) => {
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        // @ts-ignore
                        this.progress = Math.round((event.loaded * 100) / event.total);
                    }

                    this.$emit('progress', {
                        originalEvent: event,
                        progress: this.progress
                    });
                });

                xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        // @ts-ignore
                        this.progress = 0;

                        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                            if (this.fileLimit) {
                                this.uploadedFileCount += this.files.length;
                            }

                            this.$emit('upload', {
                                xhr: xhr,
                                files: this.files
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.$emit('error', {
                                xhr: xhr,
                                files: this.files
                            });
                        }

                        this.uploadedFiles.push(...this.files);
                        this.clear();
                    }
                };

                xhr.open('POST', this.url, true);

                this.$emit('before-send', {
                    xhr: xhr,
                    formData: formData
                });

                xhr.withCredentials = this.withCredentials;

                xhr.send(formData);
            }
    
            this.$emit('has-uploaded', true);
        },
        choose() {
            this.$refs.fileInput.click();
        },
        clear() {
            this.files = [];
            this.messages = [];
            this.$emit('clear');
            this.$emit('has-files', false);
        },
        onFocus() {
            this.focused = true;
        },
        onBlur() {
            this.focused = false;
        },
        getFileExtension(file: MediaFile) {
            return '.' + file.name.split('.').pop();
        },
        isImage(file: MediaFile) {
            return /^image\//.test(file.type);
        },
        isVideo(file: MediaFile) {
            return /^video\//.test(file.type);
        },
        generateUniqueFileName(file: any) {
            let prefix = this.isImage(file) ? 'image' : 'video';
            let fileUniqueId = randomNumber(18);
            let fileExtension = file.split('.').pop();
            return `${prefix}-${fileUniqueId}.${fileExtension}`;
        },
        getMediaTypeSupported() {
            const mediaType = this.mediaType.toLowerCase();
            if (mediaType === 'image') {
                return this.acceptedTypes = this.accept ? this.accept.split(',').filter(type => !type.includes('video')).join(', ') : 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png';
            } else if (mediaType === 'video') {
                return this.acceptedTypes = this.accept ? this.accept.split(',').filter(type => !type.includes('image')).join(', ') : 'video/mp4, video/webm, video/avi';
            } else {
                return this.acceptedTypes = (this.accept || 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, video/mp4, video/webm, video/avi');
            }
        },
        getAllSupportedMediaTypes() {
            const imageTypes = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'svg'];
            const videoTypes = ['mp4', 'webm', 'avi', 'mov', 'mkv'];
            const supportedTypes = this.acceptedTypes.includes('image/*') ? imageTypes : this.acceptedTypes.includes('video/*') ? videoTypes : [...imageTypes, ...videoTypes];

            return supportedTypes.map(type => type.toUpperCase());
        }
    },
    computed: {
        hasFiles() {
            return Boolean(this.files && this.files.length > 0);
        },
        hasUploadedFiles() {
            return Boolean(this.uploadedFiles && this.uploadedFiles.length > 0);
        },
        chooseDisabled() {
            return this.disabled || Boolean(this.fileLimit && this.fileLimit <= this.files.length);
        },
        uploadDisabled() {
            return this.disabled || !this.hasFiles || Boolean(this.fileLimit && this.fileLimit < this.files.length);
        },
        cancelDisabled() {
            return this.disabled || !this.hasFiles;
        },
        hasContentInsideTemplateOrEmpty() {
            if (this.$slots.default && this.$slots.default().length > 0) {
                return this.$slots.default().every(slot => {
                    return slot.type === 'template' || slot.type === Comment;
                });
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        supportedFileTypes() {
            const specialCases: Record<string, string> = {
                'svg+xml': 'svg',
                'x-matroska': 'mkv',
                'quicktime': 'mov',
            };
            return [...new Set(this.acceptedTypes.split(',').map(type => {
                const fileType = type.trim().split('/')[1];
                return fileType.includes('*') ? this.getAllSupportedMediaTypes().join(', ') : (specialCases[fileType] || fileType).toUpperCase();
            }))].join(', ');
        }
    },
    components: {
        ErrorMessage: Message,
        FontAwesomeIcon
    },
}
</script>

<template>...</template>


does your current code result in any errors in the browser developer tools console? where does your code attempt to call anything in the child component?

You have calling through emissions

I stopped having those years ago - but how does your posted code attempt to do what you want? You asked what am I doing wrong - and the only thing I can see is that you aren't even trying to call a function in the child from the parent - so, I guess the answer to what am I doing wrong is, that you aren't doing anything

I already solved this problem by adding this "await mediaImport?.value?.upload();" but I had to do it in a separate script because when I had "
BTW do not use String Boolean etc. as a type. See this

Use event bus. For example useEventBus

Here are two ways you might go about doing this:

On the click of a button in the parent component, pass a new prop to the child. Write a watch on that prop and trigger the method which you want to execute from the watch in the child component.
Use defineExpose() and access it using the ref in the parent component.


Only two way? ))
